# XML Serialization with Navigation Properties

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I´m a pretty new MVC developer, and I´m having a little trouble with serializing to XML my classes.

I currently have the following classes:

```
  public class UserClass
{

    public int UserId{ get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public bool LogicalDelete { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Phone> Phone{ get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<EventList> Event{ get; set; }
}


public class Phone
{
    public int TelefonosId { get; set; }
    public string Phone{ get; set; }
    public bool Mobile{ get; set; }

    public int UsuarioId { get; set; }
    public virtual UserClass User { get; set; }
}
```

The serializer method I´m calling from the UserController is the following:

```
public void ExportToXML()
   {
        var data = mydb.User.ToList();

        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=testXML.xml");
        Response.ContentType = "text/xml";

        var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(data.GetType());
        serializer.Serialize(Response.OutputStream, data);
   }
```

And then comes the issue. When I try to serialize, the navigation properties from the User class give me a reflecting type error on the "GetType" call. It works just fine without them (I was able to export the User list correctly, without Phones).

What am I missing? Is there something I could be doing better?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Assuming you're getting an exception, can you share the complete `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception?

Comment: Is the error you are getting `Cannot serialize member UserClass.Phone of type System.Collections.Generic.ICollection 1[[Phone]] because it is an interface.`?  That's the error I see when I tried to create a [mcve] here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/NF9BpZ

Comment: Yes, thats exactly the error Im getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem in the following way:

```
XDocument xmlDocument = new XDocument(
                new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),

                new XComment("Exporting Users to XML"),

                new XElement("Users",

                    from usu in db.Users.ToList()
                    select new XElement("User", new XElement("Email", usu.Email),
                                new XElement("FirstName", usu.FirstName),
                                new XElement("LastName", usu.LastName),
                                new XElement("Deleted", usu.LogicalDelete),
                                  from tel in usu.Phones.ToList()
                                  select new XElement("Phone",
                                new XElement("Phone", tel.Phone),
                                new XElement("Mobile", tel.Mobile)))
                            ));
            xmlDocument.Save("D:\\user.xml");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace the interface `ICollection` with an implementation of this interface.

For example, replace:

```
public virtual ICollection<Phone> Phone{ get; set; }
```

with:

```
public virtual List<Phone> Phone{ get; set; }
```

Or you can also implement the [`IXmlSerializable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable(v=vs.110).aspx) in the `UserClass` and describe how to serialize this collection by providing your own serialization logic.

Comment: After I did this, I still was getting the same issue (the error in reflecting types).

Comment: Can you add the exact error message in your question ?